# Apply mongoDB query to javascript object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongoDB query, like such

`{ $inc: {bar: 3} }`

I'd like to apply it to my javascript object without actually passing it through mongoDB

```
let foo = {bar: 1}
MongoQuery.apply(foo, { $inc: {bar: 3} }) // Is this possible?
console.log(foo) // {bar: 4}
```

My use-case is to use the result locally without awaiting the DB call.

I tried searching for libraries that could achieve this, but found none.

Comment: the query should be run inside mongodb so actually doing the increment in ur server defeats the purpose?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-mock maybe this

Comment: @cmghess, The update should be run both on the server and DB without writing the code twice. The local update should be pushed to cache, while DB is for persistence. I use it in Meteor.js project, thus I cannot use `findOneAndUpdate` which would kind-of solve my problem.
mongo-mock looks promising!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [modifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modifyjs) is what I was looking for:

```
import modify from 'modifyjs'

const foo = {bar: 1}
const result = modify(foo, { $inc: {bar: 3} })
console.log(result) // {bar: 4}
```

I found this package by searching through the codebase of [mongo-mock](https://npmjs.com/package/mongo-mock), which mocks the whole mongoDB API.